# why my ILSpy shows a different version of code?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C# and .net, sorry if my question sounds stupid.

I follow an onlilne tutorial which teaches how to insepect compiled code, below is a snapshot from the instructor:
[image]

And below is a screenshot from my pc:
[image]

You can see that mine is purely IL code, and even if I change the setting to C#:
[image]
there is no `<Main>d_0` section anymore, and the code is purely C# code.
so how can I switch to the view so that I can see the "more advanced C# code" just like the instructor's?

Comment: See the drop-down box in the toolbar that says "IL"? Change that to "C#".

Comment: @Corey Thanks for your answer. I have actually done that, but it still doesn't work, please refer to my edited post which I just added a new screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a more modern version of ILSpy compared to your instructor. Your more modern version can better *reverse* C#'s newer language-features to simpler C# code.

For example, older versions of ILSpy could not decompile `async` methods with `await` keywords back into single source methods, but instead would show them as their *compiled* multi-method state-machines (as you're seeing with how `TaskAwaiter` is exposed in `<Main>d_0`).

If you want the same display as your instructor you need to use the same version of ILSpy as them. From the screenshot it looks like they're using version 4 or earlier of ILSpy - which is *very* outdated by now. You should tell your instructor to get the latest version (as of November 2020 it's version 6.1).

Comment: I suspect that you could also reduce the version from `C# 8.0`. Which may limit the language patterns that ILSpy will try to use.

Comment: OP could turn off "Decompile async methods" to get the same view.

Answer (score 0):

The ILSpy toolbar has a group of buttons that lets you choose between

- Show only public types and members
- Show public, private and internal (the default)
- Show all types and members (including compiler-generated)

If you pick "Show all types and members" you'll see the compiler-generated class and its MoveNext method even if decompilation of the `async` feature is enabled.