# ILSpy，How to make IL Code looks more like native C# instead of machine code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, ilspy, dnspy

[this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uWG9.png)

[this is what i want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCEll.png)

I've only just started using ILSpy，the dll is compined with Unity Self，and i just drag the Assembly-CSharp.dll into ILSpy，I have searched for a long time but nothing leaned.Is there some setting i need?

Comment: Welcome to SO. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868167/why-my-ilspy-shows-a-different-version-of-code) for some clues.

Comment: you need to de compile the code, maybe use reflector.

Comment: Try dotPeek or dnSpy

Answer (score 2):

In the top menubar of ILSpy you can see a combobox/dropdown, which selects the decompiler's output target language. I suspect it is set to `IL` in your case. Change its value to C#, and your situation should improve...

Comment: thanks a lot ,this really help ... i cant believe i ask such a stuip quesiton... thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

What do you even mean?

C# code is COMPILED INTO IL CODE.

IL Code does not look like C# code because it is another language. If you drag an assembly into ILSpy it can only show you the IL - why on earth would it show you anything that even remotely looks like C# Code? ILSpy is there to show you the IL Code - you can not make that IL Code look like C# code. This is like "how do I make English follow German syntax".

Now, there are decompilers. The answer for them is: Write IL code as the compiler would.

Comment: IlSpy is also a decompiler  as descriped in [Microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ilspy/9mxfbkfvsq13?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) "ILSpy is the open-source .NET assembly browser and **decompiler**"